# How to create a javascript bookmarklet to paste text into all textareas on webpage?

Tags: javascript, textarea, bookmarklet

I have the following code which works to a degree with text fields but not textareas

```
javascript:(function(){for(var%20text=prompt('enter%20text%20to%20fill')||'',ins=document.getElementsByTagName('input'),it,m=ins.length,i=0;i<m;i++){it=ins[i];if(it.name=='text')it.value=text;};}());
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to make the code readable please!

Answer (score 3):

A simplified example, based on your bookmarklet:

**Readable version:**

```
(function(){
  var t = prompt('enter text to fill') || '',
  ta = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'), n = ta.length;
  while(n--){
    ta[n].value = t;
  }
}());
```

**Bookmarklet:**

```
javascript:(function(){var%20t=prompt('enter%20text%20to%20fill')||'',ta=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'),n=ta.length;while(n--){ta[n].value=t;}}());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
ins=document.getElementsByTagName('input')
```

to

```
ins=document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')
```

and *remove*

```
if(it.name=='text')
```

Note: this will insert your text into all textareas in the document